# VBA Application.inputbox type 8 returns cell value instead of range

Tags: excel, vba, range

So I need my user to select a cell, which my code then converts to a column number in order to obtain the sum of the entire column (without the user having to select the entire column).

E.g., user selects cell B3, the code should return B3 (or $B$3), and I can go on.
However, whatever I try, it comes up with the value in cell B3 instead.

Refer to sample code below:

```
Dim Selection As Range
Dim Column As String

Set Selection = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select a cell.", Title:="Selection", Type:=8)


MsgBox Selection

End Sub
```

Anybody has any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Don't use `Selection` as a variable name... but in any case, you just need `.Address` to get a range's address, or `.Column` to return its column number.

Comment: Try selecting multiple cells - you'll get an exception. If there is only one cell selected - msgbox will show it's value as like `Selection.Value`